# DAO architecture approach:based on HibernateDaoSupport or on EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to manage all DAO in the same way:

1) Create one base class with entity operations like save, update, delete, etc.
2) Each DAO inherits to base class and performs base class operations.
3) All entities also will have one root.

```java
public abstract BaseDao {
...
   @Transactional
   public T update(T entity) throws DataAccessException {
       getHibernateTemplate().update(entity);
       return entity;
   }
}
...
public MemberDao extends BaseDao {
...
   @Override
   @Transactional
   public IMember update(IMember member) throws DataAccessException {
       super.update(member);
       return member;
   }
}
```

and there are two possible way:

1) based on `HibernateDaoSupport and getHibernateTemplate()`
2) based on `getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager()`

**Main question is approach based on *hibernateTemplate* or on *entityManager*  - which of them will be better to use?**
Underlying JPA provider in both cases is Hibernate.

Comment: Neither. Just inject the `EntityManager` with `@PersistenceContext`. I suggest a read of http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight. Note that questions like this will generally give opinionated answers. Also don't reinvent the wheel and use [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) for the crud stuff.

Comment: Do you understand the differences between Hibernate and JPA?

Comment: Why don't you use Spring-data-jpa? That's exactly what it's for. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/

Comment: **Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye** - Yes, of course, but I meant what kind of way to use to perform operations on entities.

**M. Deinum,  JB Nizet**- thank you, CrudRepository is something I needed.